# Angular-Meteor - How can I include ng template in package-based design?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, meteor-packages

I have an Angular-Meteor application working.  I would like to package Angular templates and associated controller into a Meteor package, and inject these templates into my main application by adding that package.

What is best approach?

**Update 2015-08-26 - I figured out how to add a template, documented below.  But how to have a Meteor package inject the template's Angular controller into the base application?**

A key tie-in is Angular UI-router.

I have a base application that includes my package named **packageprefix:packagename**.  Inside this package I have my code in the root of the package folder:
myPackagedPage.ng.html - the Angular HTML template
myPackagedPage.js - the associated Angular controller

From my main application, I tried creating a route to my Angular template like so:

```
angular.module('parentModule',[
    'angular-meteor',
    'ui.router',
    'angularify.semantic.sidebar'
])

.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    console.log("app.js config!");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'client/views/home/home.ng.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        .state('myPackagedPage', {
            url: '/myPackagedPage',
            templateUrl: 'packageprefix_packagename/myPackagedPage.ng.html',
            controller: 'MyPackagedPageCtrl'
        })
    ;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}])
```

The application successfully finds the myPackagedPage.ng.html file and renders it.  But how to add the controller?

I tried adding this in my package but the controller functions does not get called.

```
console.log("myPackagedPage.js loaded");
angular.module('parentModule')

.controller('MyPackagedPageCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        console.log("MyPackagedPageCtrl");
    }])
;
```

I get an error:

```
Argument 'MyPackagedPageCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this working now.  Here is the approach that works for me, to inject an Angular Controller + template in a Meteor package, into the containing application.

In my package.js, I have this

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.3');
    api.use('angular:angular@1.4.4', 'client');
    api.use("urigo:angular@0.9.3", 'client');
    api.use("session@1.1.0", 'client');

    //api.use('angularui:angular-ui-router@0.2.15', 'client');
    api.addFiles('interests.js', 'client');
    api.addFiles('interests.ng.html', 'client');

    api.export("InterestsCtrl", "client")
});
```

Note you must export your controller, so that the parent application may access it.

In my package, called **ramshackle:bigd-interests**, I have these files at the root level:  **package.js**, **interests.ng.html**, and **interests.js**.  **interests.js** injects the Angular controller, the Anguilar UI-router route to the template, and a sidebar link into the parent application.  It accomplishes this by using the Meteor Session.  I played with other means of doing this but Session was the only thing that worked.  Just be careful to properly scope your session variable names.

```
//add controllers
var controllers = Session.get("BIGD.controllers");
if (!controllers) controllers = {};

var interestsCtrlSpec = "'$scope', InterestsCtrl";

InterestsCtrl = function($scope){
    console.log("InterestsCtrl running");
};
controllers.InterestsCtrl = interestsCtrlSpec;
Session.set("BIGD.controllers", controllers);

//add routes
var routes = Session.get("BIGD.routes");
if (!routes) routes = {};
routes.interests = {
    url: '/interests',
    templateUrl: 'ramshackle_bigd-interests_interests.ng.html',
    controller: 'InterestsCtrl'
};
Session.set("BIGD.routes", routes);

//add sidebar links
//the key determines sorting order
var sidebar = Session.get("BIGD.sidebar");
if (!sidebar) sidebar = {};
sidebar["interests"] = {
    url: '/interests',
    templateUrl: 'ramshackle_bigd-interests_interests.ng.html',
    controller: 'InterestsCtrl',
    rank: 5
};
Session.set("BIGD.sidebar", sidebar);

var interestsItem = {label: 'Interests', link: '/interests', icon: "rocket"};
```

In my parent application's **app.js** , I dynamically loaded the controllers and routes from the session like this:

```
angular.module('bigdam',[
    'angular-meteor',
    'ui.router',
    'angularify.semantic.sidebar',
    'nvd3',
    'leaflet-directive',
    'ui.router.history'
])

    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
        //console.log("app.js config!");
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        //add a static state
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'client/views/home/home.ng.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            });

        //add the dynamic routes/states from other Meteor packages
        for (var stateId in routes) {
            var route = routes[stateId];
            $stateProvider
                .state(stateId, route);
        }

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }])
;

//Declare the controllers from plugins
for (var controllerId in controllers) {
    var controllerSpec = controllers[controllerId];
    var controllerSpecArray = eval("[" + controllerSpec + "]")
    angular.module('bigdam').controller(controllerId, controllerSpecArray);
}
```

So now, when I create a new Meteor package, and follow the convention described above, its controllers, routes, and sidebar links get loaded into the main application.